# multipeer connectivity - How can I set up to have one host sending out data to multiple peers?

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I have the code for the basic multipeer connectivity so that a chat can be set up between two devices and send a file to one other device. But how can I have it so there is one host, to whom other devices can connect to?

Answer (score 0):

You can add other devices but all the devices share with each other, not just host -> connected peers.